# Kendo Grid Loading Spinner is not in the center of the screen

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo Grid without fixed height and with a 50-100 entries in one page. The problem is that when I'm scrolling to down of the page and changing the page the loading spinner appears in the middle of the grid, which is not visible.

How to change this so the loading spinner appear in the middle of visible area of the grid?

Comment: Well, you can't. The kendo spinner shows in the center of the div that contains the grid, so, if the grid is too big and you scroll down a lot, you won't see the spinner in its center

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is some clean solution for you.

Well, if ajax is run after you change page you can do it manually, something like this:

I added into layout page div

```
<div id="loading"></div>
```

Then I include javascript with following code

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    Loading(false);
});

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    Loading(true);
});

function Loading(isOn) {
    kendo.ui.progress($('#loading'), isOn);
}
```

and in the end I just modified css how I needed it

```
#gridId .k-loading-image{
    background-image:none;
}

.k-loading-color{
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

In my case I display loading bar for whole screen in every ajax call. However how I said, it will work only with ajax calls ... With some small modification it can helps you ..